# Transform array of arrays into variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have that code:

```js
var filters = [];
if (Locality && Locality != '') {

    filters.push(["==", 'Locality', Locality]);
}

if (PriceStart && PriceStart != '') {

    filters.push([">=", 'Price', PriceStart]);
}

if (PriceEnd && PriceEnd != '') {

    filters.push(["<=", 'Price', PriceEnd]);
}
```

And I need to turn everything into a variable as in the example, taking into account that the positions of the array are dynamic:

```js
var new_Filter = ["all", filters[0], filters[1], filters[2]];
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: From the snippets you've provided, it looks like you've already got code that constructs `new_Filter` the way you want.  What do you need beyond what you've already shown us?

Comment: I received the following error: 

evented.js:104 Error: layers.unclustered-point.filter[1][0]: expected one of [==, !=, >, >=, <, <=, in, !in, all, any, none, has, !has], ==,Locality,Lisboa found

Comment: That error isn't coming from the code you've posted above.  You're going to have to post all of your relevant code.  There's just not enough info here to help you.

Comment: Ok, I need to transform the array of arrays into this, but with filters var, not works.

I need to do something like this: new_Filter = ["all", ["==", 'Locality', localidade], [">=", 'Price', precoStart], ["<=", 'Price', precoEnd]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but it seems as though you want a piece of code which puts all the elements of filters into another array called new_filters with the first element of new_filters being "all".

Try this:

```
var new_filters = ["all"];
for(i = 0; i < filters.length; i++){
    new_filters.push(filters[i]);
}
```

Comment: It works! That was what he intended, but he could not think. Thank you!